# Are Parathreads fully functional on Kusama?

Tags: kusama, parathread

I was told that after parachains, one of the next steps is parathreads, where can I find information about parathreads estimated release date on Kusama?

PS: I read the following on Reddit:

> Well parathread cannot send state transition proofs for Relay Chain validators for now I think. So yes, they exists, because before becoming a parachain, the previous stage is being a parathread, but they cannot do anything

Does this mean they exist but they are not functional yet? When can we expect fully functional parathreads on Kusama?

Comment: From what I can find on https://polkadot.network/launch-roadmap , parathreads are next on the roadmap. But if I go to the frontend, there are already a bunch of parathreads active.
Maybe the parathreads are already fully functioning, but it's the launching of a parathread that is being worked on? 
Can anyone else comment on this?

Comment: Please always link to source materials you reference 

Answer (score 5):

The Reddit answer is correct. They exist as an abstraction because the lifecycle of a parachain starts from and ends in being a parathread, but the core functionality (i.e. pay-as-you-go, generating para-blocks and proofs) are not active/fully implemented yet.

Comment: Any news about when will be parathreads fully functional?